# Inheritance mapping asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, casting, mapping

I have a rather basic problem, but I am searching the best approach for this.

I have two classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class BudgetEntry
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(127)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? Category1Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category 1")]

    public Category1Dictionary Category1 { get; set; }

    public Category2Dictionary Category2 { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

And second one, which derives first one:

```
public class BudgetEntryViewModel : BudgetEntry
{
    public string PeriodName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I have BudgetEntry object, and want to map it as BudgetEntryViewModel.
This is what i tried:

```
BudgetEntry item = new BudgetEntry() { /*seed data here*/ };
(BudgetEntryViewModel)item;
```

But this approach causes error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Budget.Models.BudgetEntry' to type
>   'Budget.Models.BudgetEntryViewModel'.'

Comment: why you need cast to BudgetEntryViewModel?

Comment: BudgetEntry is Data transfer object(I am using EF, and this object is used to create table) and I want to have additional properties in my class.